# How to specify dynamic list height with dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have lists like those:

```
<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>
<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>
<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>

<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>
<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>
<ul class='fixture'><li>...html table...</li></ul>
```

I gave the `li` a height of 23 but when the content of my html table is more than 23 the content interferes with `li` beneath it. I tried to make min-height for li and leave the height unspecified but that did not work. I want to know if anybody can help me on how to increase the height of `li` when its content's height is higher than other `li`?

Comment: This Code is not enough to understand the problem. Can you recreate the problem at jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the height from your LI. The height is likely used to separate the lines (correct me if I'm wrong). An easy solution is to translate it to line-height:

```
li {
  line-height:23px;
}
```

However, this will keep the lines spaced evenly. You may want to separate LI's by a bit more than the lines, in order to visually group list item lines better together. To do this, add padding along with the line height:

```
li {
  line-height:13px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Does this give you the effect you're looking for?

Comment: If the content between `<li></li>` is an html table, if the table has several rows, won't the line height interfere somewhat with the presentation, or will the table inside `<li></li>` have its own `line-height` and won't be affected? - I'm just imagining gaps in the presentation based on editing line-height, though I may be misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: Gersande, line-height will cascade from the list item to tags inside the list item, which could include a table (e.g. http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/oxDBH). However, this can be fixed by adding a different line height to the table within the LI, or to the LI itself, since it appears that only tabular content is included in the LI.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any `height` attribute you have assigned to the `li`. Without a height specified it will adjust automatically.